# Is $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{n-1}\equiv -1\pmod {2n}\Leftrightarrow \text{$n$ is prime }\equiv 3\pmod 4$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, conjectures

I was looking at the [*Agoh-Giuga Conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh%E2%80%93Giuga_conjecture), namely, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{n-1}\equiv-1\pmod n\Leftrightarrow n\text{ is prime.}\tag1$$

I decided to see if I could *prove* it, expecting lots of difficulty; and I believe I was able to prove that if $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$ then Eq. $(1)$ $\equiv -1\pmod {2n}$.

---

*Proof*: Restating the conjecture, there exists an integer $k$ such that $$\begin{align}kn&=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{n-1} \\ &= 2 +\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}i^{n-1} \\ &= 2\big(1+2^{n-2}\big)+\sum_{i=3}^{n-1}i^{n-1}.\tag2\end{align}$$ Let's consider for $n>3$. Now any prime $>3$ is congruent to $\pm 1$ modulo $6$. Therefore, by order of substitution, $$k\big(6n\pm 1\big)=\text{Eq. }(2).$$ By rearranging, $$6nk-2\big(1+2^{n-2}\big)=\mp k+\sum_{i=3}^{n-1}i^{n-1}.$$ Note that if $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$ then the sum of strictly the powers is equal to $($the sum of an even number of odd numbers) $+$ $($the sum of an even number of even numbers). Therefore, that entire sum is even. Since the LHS is divisible by $2$, then that means $k$ also must be divisible by $2$.

Let $k=2j$, then we re-write that $$\begin{align}2jn&=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{n-1} \\ \therefore \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{n-1}\equiv -1\pmod {2n}&\Leftrightarrow \text{$n$ is prime}\equiv 3\pmod 4.\end{align}$$ $$\quad\,\,\,\binom{\text{Assuming the conjecture}}{\text{is valid for all prime $n$}}$$ Of course $n>2$ since $2\not\equiv 3\pmod 4$. $\;\bigcirc$

---

Is my proof correct? Can it be written differently and in a better fashion? Is there anything new on this conjecture thus far?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First point: you say that if $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then Eq.(1) $\equiv -1 \pmod {2p}$. What is $p$'s relation to $n$ here?  

Second point: $1 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{n-1} = 2 + \sum\limits_{i=2}^{n-2}i^{n-1} + (n-1)^{n-1}$. You seem to have omitted that last term. I didn't follow much after that.

Comment: @TobErnack woops I don't know why I wrote $p$. Maybe I just got confused... also, $1^{n-1}$ is $1$, so I just let $i=2$, and now we have $n-2$ summands of powers, correct?

Comment: But you also changed the upper limit of the sum from $n-1$ to $n-2$, so you also need to include the last term which was $(n-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @TobErnack oh wait. Instead of $i^{n-1}$, I think I was supposed to write $i^{n-2}$ in regards to that case... but doesn't matter. I will add in that term... tomorrow :)

Comment: No, even if you correct the mistakes/typos in the summation limit and powers in Eq.2, the proof would be wrong. What you would prove is that if there is a $k$ that satisfies Eq.2 and if $n\equiv 3 \mod 4$ is a prime then it follows that $k$ is even. You do not prove that $n$ has to be prime nor that if it is a prime there is a $k$ for which Eq.2 is valid.

Comment: @RonaldBlaak it is a conjecture that $n$ is prime. Also, I don't need to add the term. I will just change the indice to $n-1$. This is not a *proof* proof. It is a proof that this is true *assuming* the conjecture is true.

Comment: Typos: exponents $n-3$ should be $n-1$, then it is ok but it can be done easier. Since for a prime $p$ we have $1+\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^{p-1} \equiv 0$ mod $p$ and for any number $n \equiv 3$ mod 4 we have $1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^{n-1} \equiv  1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \equiv 0 \mod 2$ (only need to count the number of odd i's) it follows that for $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$ we find $1+\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^{p-1} \equiv 0 \mod 2 p$.

Comment: @RonaldBlaak thanks for noticing the typos.... also, thanks for the short proof :)